# Sort array inside object in list<object>

Tags: c#, linq

I have home object : `id` , `FirstName`, `Lastname`, `Fees[ ]`

Fees is object contain Amount description DueDate ...

home object include the Fees array

I have list of homes and every home has array/list from fees

I need to sort the fees depend on the Duedate in each object

```
for (int i = 0; i < homes.Length; i++)
  {
   homes[i].Fees = homes[i].Fees.OrderBy(si => si.DueDate).ToArray();
  }
```

Can I find one statement instead of four statements?

Comment: This should probably be on codereview.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can I find one statement instead of three statements?

That should rarely be your goal.

However; you say that `Fees` is an array; if that is the case, you can avoid some work by sorting in-place rather than creating a clone of the array:

```
foreach(var home in homes) {
   Array.Sort(home.Fees, (x,y) => x.DueDate.CompareTo(y.DueDate));
}
```